# Can't we send an integer along jQuery .post method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form and I want to send a integer from one of the textbox back to the server. I was using $.post() and wrote code as follows:

```
$.post("/getvalue",$("#info1").val, function(data,status){
            alert("reached server");
            $("#info2").val(data);
        });
```

This turned out to be not working or more clearly its sending a zero value to server. I also tried following version of above code:

```
$.post("/getvalue",$("#info1").serialize(), function(data,status){
            alert("reached server");
            $("#info2").val(data);
        });

$.post("/getvalue",'$("#info1").serialize()', function(data,status){
            alert("reached server");
            $("#info2").val(data);
        });
```

Then I also tried to store text box value into a variable and send it as follow:

```
var value= $("#info1").val();
$.post("/getvalue",'value', function(data,status){
            alert("reached server");
            $("#info2").val(data);
        });
```

Also I tried:

```
var value= $("#info1").val();
$.post("/getvalue",value, function(data,status){
            alert("reached server");
            $("#info2").val(data);
        });
```

But none of all these code works. So now my Query is that Can we not pass an integer or variable containing integer using $.post(). As the documentation says we can do so. How is it possible to do so... Am I wrong somewhere??? Believe me there are no coding errors (like parenthesis and semicolons etc..) in my full code.

I know about the $.ajax() method of doing so, but I just wanted to know the scope for doing it using simple $.post().

Please someone care to lend a hand.

Thanx

Comment: it would be helpful to also show what your server side script is doing. furthermore, you should send a key/value pair to server when using $.post() which you are doing only in once case when calling serialize() in your code. Does your $('#info1') element have a 'name' attribute?

Comment: How is Java relevant here?

Comment: From the [jQuery source code for $.post](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.post) post is a very short function that calls [$.ajax](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.ajax), and `$.ajax` performs type conversion on the `data` parameter when it is not a String. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) say it wants an Object or a String.  So, why not send an object like `{val: value}` as the 2nd parameter instead of a bare integer, change the server side code, and be happy with following the spec?

Comment: Aplogies George..I removed java tag

Comment: @Paul: I didn't quite get u. Are u trying to say that I should store a int value from txtbox into a js variable and again store variable into an object..

Comment: Yes.  If you want to save steps, it can be like this: `$.post("/getvalue",{'value': $("#info1").val()}, function(data,status){ ...`  -- but you have to go to the server code and make sure it is set up to decode what is sent, which is `{'value': '23'}` or similar. Also, you should be trying  `console.log($("info1".val());` to see if that is giving you the number.

Answer (score 1):

Use **parseInt()** to convert into interger

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseInt()` in order to be able to convert it into an interger.

You can read something about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Also take a look at your `$.post("/getvalue",$("#info1").val` Your missing the () at the end of .val It shall look like `.val()`